# c++ Instance of class in same class, using constructor

Tags: c++

I have class A, is it possible to make sth like this? A(A(A()))? I mean creating some object in constructor and so on?

```
class A {
private:
    A *a;
public:
    A(){
        printf("A()\n");
    }


    A( A * var){
        printf("A(A)\n");
        a = var;
    }
};




  int main() {
        A x = A(A(A()));

        return 0;
  };
```

and this give me output `A()`, i mean why not `A() A(A) A(A)`? My A class represent a memory cell so A(1) is pointing to `array[1]` but `A(A(1))` is sth like `array[array[1]]`. But i don't have idea how to implement this, only one object is created. (this A class is just an example of what I want to achieve)

Comment: You're using the move constructor, not the conversion constructor `A(A* var)` - and the move is elided so you wouldn't notice that one either.

Comment: so its not possible? i've implemented move constructor but doesnt help

Comment: Sure, you can do something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/eqxTTh)

Comment: An `A` isn't a `A*`, so it isn't clear to me why you expect the `A(A* var)` constructor to be used.

Comment: `A()` gives you a temporary instance, not a pointer. That said, I think you're describing a so-called "XY problem" (research that term online). As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: But without using new?

Comment: You could hide the `new`/`delete` using a `unqiue_ptr` and `make_unique`: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/ah8Y48)

Comment: but i want as i write above, A(A(A(A)))

Comment: Have you tried using templates?

Comment: I don't know of a way to get `A(A(A(A))))` to create more than one instance in C++17 or later. You could create a helper function if you want to avoid typing `make_unique`: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/he4bed)

Comment: Or you could create a constructor that creates all the instances you want recursively: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/8vj5fc)

Comment: It sounds like you want `A(A())` to create an `A` object that references another. The problem with that is that there is no way to distinguish this between a call to the copy/move constructor. Passing an object to the constructor of its own class is exactly how you ask for that object to be copied (or moved) into a new instance. You could perhaps distinguish this case in your code with a static factory function, like `static A nested(A);` and then you could do `A::nested(A::nested(A()))` for example.